# How to setup a Mac for kiosk mode video presentation?

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, video, search

My situation is: 2 iMacs (Lion), one displays a slide show and the other one a video.

If a user comes to the iMac and wants to play the video again, he should be able to play the video with one click (mice or keyboard). It should only play the video and disable every other feature/software on the Mac.

I could imagine theres already a software like that, and if you want to come out of that "presentation"-mode you have to press a special keyboard shortcut to do that.

Comment: What file format is your video file in? That might limit the choices.

Comment: The are some other questions and answers about configuring a Mac in kiosk mode, please see: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14277/how-to-kiosk-mode-a-web-page-osx-chrome, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61457/how-to-configure-os-x-for-exhibitions and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/is-there-a-way-to-replace-finder-altogether.